# Divide the each element in column of a matrix by the mean value of that column

Tags: python, mean

So, I am new to python and pandas.
I am having a matrix in the form

```
age  sex  cpt  rbp   sc  fbs  rer     
28    0   12    0.6  1   20    30    
29     1  20    1.1  0    10   20    
30    1    2     2.0 0    15   19
```

I want to divide each element of the column by the mean value of each respective column.

How can I do this using pandas?

For example >>for age column
The mean is around 28+29+30/3=29
So now divide each element of age column by 29.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your df columns, making adjustments within the loop like so:

```
for i in df:
    df[i] = df[i] / df[i].mean()
```

This results in:

```
        age  sex       cpt       rbp   sc       fbs       rer
0  0.965517  0.0  1.058824  0.486486  3.0  1.333333  1.304348
1  1.000000  1.5  1.764706  0.891892  0.0  0.666667  0.869565
2  1.034483  1.5  0.176471  1.621622  0.0  1.000000  0.826087
```

Comment: Whenever you use a loop in Pandas, you almost surely do it wrong.

Comment: @DYZ Touche,  nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the means of all columns and divide by them:

```
df /= df.mean()
```